# Cant load many image in react-native-html-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pdf

I have to develop an app with complex pdf layout and many images, i used the **base64 image** cause i *cant* using url or `file:///.../my-image.jpg` to load the image, but it make my app cant generate pdf, so **what kind i can use to make generate my pdf more lighter** or **how to load image without using base64 image** ? Hopefully can help for this